# How to create correct SQL statement in delphi

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi

I am pretty new to delphi and I would like to ask how can I create a correct SQL statement / SQL string in delphi.

I have tried something like this:

```
 sql:='use [TestovaciaDb] INSERT INTO [dbo].[client]([Meno],[Priezvisko]) VALUES('+name+','+surname+')';
```

I am using MS SQL server 2012

But I am getting a exception there. Thank you

EDIT:

`meno` and `priez` are variables with values from `TEdit1` and `TEdit2`:

```
 meno:= Edit1.Text;
 priez:= Edit2.Text;
```

Comment: The same way as you'd write it in your DB management application, just [`use parameters`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Using_Parameters_in_Queries) e.g. `'INSERT INTO client (Meno, Priezvisko) VALUES (:Meno, :Priezvisko)';`. Then you'll need to fill parameter values in your query component. And, when you're asking for help, you have to provide relevant information. That you got "an exception" is pointless here. You need to provide the exact error message you got. Also would be more than useful to tell us which DB component you used (e.g. `TADOQuery`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use parameterized queries. You set the database in your ConnectionString, so you don't need to `use' it in your query.

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[client] ([Meno],[Priezvisko]) ' +
                      'VALUES(:Meno, :Priezvisko)';
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Meno').Value := Edit1.Text;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Priezvisko').Value := Edit2.Text;
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: You can use `AsString` instead of setting `ParamType` and `Value` separately: `ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Meno').AsString := Edit1.Text;`

Comment: @Remy: `AsString` isn't available for `TADOQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('Meno')` when I checked it. (Just checked again in D2007, and it's not there either in XE5.) It's there for the other datasets, but not for ADO.

Comment: Thank you. It worked, but for ParamType, I get this: TParameter does not contain a member named "ParamType". So I commented out that line and it worked. So I would like to ask what is purpose of that line with ParamType:= ftString; ?Thank you

Comment: @user2886091: Are you using DBExpress or ADO for database access? My answer is based on TADOQuery, which is for ADO. If you're using DBExpress, you probably don't need it.

Comment: this is what I am using. Btw sorry for the "lame" answers but I am new to delhpi:ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
    ADODataSet1: TADODataSet;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    ADOQuery1: TADOQuery;
    ADOQuery2: TADOQuery;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;

Comment: @user2886091: I'll edit to remove. It appears you don't need it after all.

Comment: I forget that ADO is different than other DB systems. You will have to replace `AsString` with `Value` and `ParamType` with `DataType`: `ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Meno').DataType := ftString; ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Meno').Value := Edit1.Text;`

Comment: I have 2 more quick question :) 1. What is the difference between the solution with DataType and that is in the answer which woks well? 2. Do I allways have to pull new TADOQuery object on my form, when I want for example multiple queries? Or can I define it other way??

Comment: @user2886091: 1) You only need DataType if the DB has trouble matching data types, in which case you can tell it specifically which type the column is using DataType. 2) No, you can reuse the same query if you only need to use it once. If you're going to use it a lot, use separate TADOQuery objects so the db can optimize them once and then just use them again. (And your TADOQuery components shouldn't be on your form; they should be in a separate TDataModule instead.)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `use [xxx]` at the begining of the statement. The connection you use must be already configured to point to the correct database. Just like many others said, avoid creating your sentences by using constants, instead, use paramenters.

Answer (score 0):

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.QuotedStr

Use QuotedStr function.
For example

```
sql:='use [TestovaciaDb] INSERT INTO [dbo].[client]([Meno],[Priezvisko]) VALUES('+QuotedStr(name)+','+QuotedStr(surname)+')';
```

Use QuotedStr to convert the string S to a quoted string. A single quotation mark (') is inserted at the beginning and end of S, and each single quotation mark in the string is repeated. To remove the quotation marks from a quoted string, use the AnsiDequotedStr routine.

Comment: QuotedStr would be OK for SQL Server, but not MySQL or any other database that allows \' as an escape

Comment: @GerryColl: MySQL also supports doubling quote characters to signify a single quote character, so QuotedStr will be fine.