# Searching for a title in a .MDB

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Just another task for IT. The question is:

> btnSearch: The user must be able to search for a book by entering the books title. Use an input box to get the title from the user. Display the title and the ISBN number

I have the Database with multiple tables, with multiple columns in each. The book title is in the tblBooks table.

Here's my Delphi code at the moment:

```
procedure TfrmLibrary.btnSearchClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sBookName : String;
begin
  sBookName := InputBox('Enter book Name','','') ;
  qryLibrary.Active := False;
  qryLibrary.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM tblBooks WHERE TITLE = ' + sBookName + ' ;';
  qryLibrary.Active := True;
```

Its giving me an error saying:

> Project question1 raised exception class EOLeException with message 'Parameter Karoonag has no default value' Process stopped

Oh, 'Karoonag' is the title of a book.
Please give me a hand here D:

Comment: I ever wonder why people do not write the generated SQL-Query-String into a Memo, copy-paste it and test the Query-String direct on the DB-System. Maybe it is too difficult to get the query string into a Memo `Memo1.Lines := Qry.SQL;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found what I was doing wrong.

Where I do the sql text, I was missing the quotation marks for the book. Heres my code now:

```
procedure TfrmLibrary.btnSearchClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sBookName : String;
begin
  sBookName := InputBox('Enter book Name','','') ;
  qryLibrary.Active := False;
  qryLibrary.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM tblBooks WHERE TITLE = "' + sBookName + '" ;'; //<--- ""
  qryLibrary.Active := True;
```

Comment: This is a sub-par solution. Think about what happens when the book title includes one or more quotation marks. What will your SQL look like then? When a malicious or mischievous user takes advantage of that, it's called *SQL injection*. Avoid it by using a *parameterized* query. (Italicized bits are terms you should look up or ask your instructor about in class.)

Comment: Agree with Rob. For an example of using parameterized queries, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22482437). It demonstrates using them for an INSERT, but the concept is the same for a SELECT or UPDATE SQL statement. If you insist on concatenating the string yourself instead, at least use the `QuotedStr` function to do so; it will properly escape embedded quotes.