# How to insert a query string into a FireDAC query and add ' ' to the text?

Tags: sql, delphi-10.3-rio, delphi-11-alexandria

```
procedure TForm_Main.CB_Nom_Specialite_DemandeChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DM.FDQ_Find.SQL.Clear;
  DM.FDQ_Find.open('select ID_Specialite from Specialite where Nom_Specialite =  ' + (CB_Nom_Specialite_Demande.text)  ) ;
  ID_Specialite := 0 ;
  ID_Specialite := DM.FDQ_Find.FieldByName('ID_Specialite').AsInteger ;
end;
```

[image: myimage]

Comment: Are you looking for `SQL parametrizing`?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22482437/4489263

Comment: you can escape the with a double single quote, but better is to use paramters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SysUtils.QuotedStr()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.QuotedStr):

```
DM.FDQ_Find.Open('select ID_Specialite from Specialite where Nom_Specialite = ' + QuotedStr(CB_Nom_Specialite_Demande.Text));
```

However, it would be better to use a parameterized query instead, eg:

```
DM.FDQ_Find.Open('select ID_Specialite from Specialite where Nom_Specialite = :specialite', [CB_Nom_Specialite_Demande.Text]);
```

Alternatively:

```
DM.FDQ_Find.SQL.Text := 'select ID_Specialite from Specialite where Nom_Specialite = :specialite';
DM.FDQ_Find.ParamByName('specialite').AsString := CB_Nom_Specialite_Demande.Text;
DM.FDQ_Find.Open;
```